# Graphics updating from inside double-Fold-iteration within Manipulate

Tags: graphics, manipulate

Normally, when using `Manipulate[expr, controls, options]`, the graphics updating should be carried out at the very end of expr.

But now I encounter a situation where the graphics result is evaluated at each step inside a double-`Fold`-iteration. Yes I can still adopt the method mentioned above and write following code,

```
DynamicModule[{g},
 Manipulate[
  Module[{a},
   Fold[(
      k = #2;
      Fold[(a = #2; g = v[a, k]; Pause[.05]) &, {}, Range[5]]
     ) &, {}, Range[15]];
   Dynamic@g
  ],
 {{k, 1}, ControlType -> None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {},
 SynchronousUpdating -> Automatic,
 Initialization :> (v[a_, k_] := Plot[Sin[x (a + k x)], {x, 0, 6}])]
]
```

But the problem is that I will have to first wait for the double-`Fold`-evaluation to complete and only after this can I see the updates in a queued sequence. The code I used here is but an over-simplified example and the actual code will take much longer time for computation. I wonder if it is possible to do the graphics updating at every iteration step when `v[a, k]` is evaluated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible way.  The question is how one wants to trigger the double-`Fold` calculation to begin.  In this example, I used a `Button` with `Method -> "Queued"`.

```
Manipulate[
 Dynamic@g,

 {{k, 1}, ControlType -> None},
 {{g, Graphics[{}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]}, ControlType -> None},
 {{v, v}, ControlType -> None},
 Button["go",
   Module[{a},
    Fold[(k = #2; Fold[(a = #2; g = v[a, k]; Pause[.05]) &, {}, Range[5]]) &, {}, Range[15]]],
   Method -> "Queued"],
 TrackedSymbols :> {}, SynchronousUpdating -> Automatic, 
 Initialization :> (v[a_, k_] := Plot[Sin[x (a + k x)], {x, 0, 6}])]
```

---

**Edit**

Here a simulation of the `Fold`.  Unfortunately, nesting the `Dynamic`s interferes with a clean modeling of `Fold`.  One is better off using `UpdateInterval` than `Pause`.  `Pause` happens in the kernel and can cause synchronization issues.

```
Manipulate[
 Dynamic[
  k = First@k0;
  a0 = Range[5];
  Dynamic[Refresh[
    a = First @ a0;
    If[Length@a0 > 1,
     a0 = Rest @ a0,
     k = First @ k0; If[Length@k0 > 1, k0 = Rest @ k0]];
    v[a, k],
    TrackedSymbols :> {}, UpdateInterval -> 0.05]]
  ],

 {{k, 1}, ControlType -> None}, {{a, 1}, ControlType -> None},
 {{k0, Range[15]}, ControlType -> None}, {{a0, Range[5]}, ControlType -> None},
 {{v, v}, ControlType -> None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {}, 
 Initialization :> (v[a_, k_] := Plot[Sin[x (a + k x)], {x, 0, 6}, PlotLabel -> {k, a}];)]
```

*N.B.* The `Fold` example in the OP just models a nested `Do` loop.  To model a full fledged fold, a fuller is needed to work with.

Comment: Your solution exactly solves my problem, thank you Micheal E2!

Comment: @saturasl  Thanks. I just added another solution, but the `Button` one is cleaner and less likely to cause problems as features are added to the demonstration.

Comment: @Micheal E2  I just got a trival question: In your Button solution, the current value of k can not be shown even with {Dynamic[k], Dynamic[g]}, because the evaluation is done outside the main body. I wonder if we could show both k and g simultaneously?

Comment: @ Michael E2  This problem is clearly addressed in your second solution, which I appreciate better, because it offers more controls and freedom. But I am still curious to know if we can show both g and k in the Button solution :)

Comment: @saturasl Try `Dynamic[k, TrackedSymbols :> {k}]` instead of just `Dynamic[k]`.  Or `Dynamic@Refresh[k, TrackedSymbols :> {k}]`.

Comment: It works, thanks! I also figured out the meaning of     {{v, v}, ControlType -> None}: Because controls format are executed in advance to the Initialization options. So when firstly executing control, a undefined symbol v is asigned to the variable v; then while executing initialization, the symbol v is defined to be a function name, therefore the variable v now will be automatically recognized by the local master kernel as a function name.

Answer (score 2):

You need to render `g` in FrontEnd **before** your `Fold` (or anything that changes `g`) is evaluated, thus you can monitor all changes happened to `g` in real-time. Also, you do not need `Manipulate` here. Something like this would be sufficient:

```
Dynamic[g]
Module[{a, k, v},
  v[a_, k_] := Plot[Sin[x (a + k x)], {x, 0, 6}];
  Fold[(k = #2;
     Fold[(a = #2; g = v[a, k]; Pause[.05]) &, {}, Range[5]]
     ) &, {}, Range[15]]
  ];
```

Or if you want to keep `g` local:

```
DynamicModule[{g},
  Cell[BoxData[MakeBoxes[Dynamic[g]]], "Output"] // CellPrint;
  Module[{a, k, v},
   v[a_, k_] := Plot[Sin[x (a + k x)], {x, 0, 6}];
   Fold[(k = #2;
      Fold[(a = #2; g = v[a, k]; Pause[.05]) &, {}, Range[5]]
      ) &, {}, Range[15]]
   ]
  ];
```

Comment: Yes you are right. Actually me current code is just in the first form you provided. However I want to submit my FEM code to WolframDemonstrationProject, so I will have to convert it using Manipulate. Still, thanks for your second code, there is something new to me.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution, using nested Refresh to simulate the two Folds in my previous code. In this way the graphics updating can still be put at the end of the innermost Refresh,

```
DynamicModule[{a = 1, k = 1, kprev = 1},
 Manipulate[
  Refresh[
   Refresh[
    Pause[.05];
    If[k != kprev, kprev = k; a = 1];
    g = v[a, k];
    Row[{Dynamic[a], Dynamic[k], Dynamic[g]}, ", "],

    If[run && a <= 5, a++];
    UpdateInterval -> If[run, If[a <= 5, 0, Infinity], Infinity]
   ],
   If[run && a > 5 && k <= 10, k++];
   UpdateInterval -> If[run, If[k <= 10, 0, Infinity], Infinity]
  ],

 {{run, False}, {True, False}, ControlType -> Checkbox},
 TrackedSymbols :> {run, a, k},
 SynchronousUpdating -> Automatic,
 Initialization :> (v[a_, k_] := 
 Plot[Sin[x (a + k x)], {x, 0, 6}, ImageSize -> 200])
]]
```

The remaining problem is, in this way the nested folds are destroyed and so is the efficiency advantage of using Fold...

Comment: I managed to come up with a possible solution, but this one may have efficiency issue. Hope someone can help to improve it.